# Resharper Broken References Visual Studio 2019 .Net Framework

Tags: .net, resharper, mstest, .net-framework-version

I'm having a problem regarding project references. 
My Environment Versions:

- Resharper 2019.2.3
- Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.5
- .csproj .Net Framework 4.7.2 MsTests

I've to hide somedata from my code, regarding company policies; 
The code builds success fully, I can run my tests successfully, but references shows like:

**Test Class**
[image: Error on MsTest class]
**Test Class Builder with Moq**
[image: Moq Reference Error]

I've already tried:

- Cleared Resharper Caches;
- Cleared Packages Folder;
- Cleared .vs folder;
- Run Project CleanUp;

Any sugestions regarding this?

[image: Imported References]